# How do i Typeorm connection pool configuration?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I used Typeorm with NestJS

I want to config connection Pool more than 10.

But always max connection 10....

```js
// My Typeorm config
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies'

const config: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT || '5432'),
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASS,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
  migrationsTableName: 'migration',
  migrations: ['src/db/migrations/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/db/migrations',
  },
  extra: {
    max: 30
  }
}

export default config
```

What should i do for postgres connection more than 10?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the poolSize, example below adjusting it to 20.

```
// My Typeorm config
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies'

const config: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT || '5432'),
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASS,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
  migrationsTableName: 'migration',
  migrations: ['src/db/migrations/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/db/migrations',
  },
  poolSize: 20,
}

export default config
```

Source: https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#common-data-source-options